# How to add a single representative color bar for multiple spatial subplots in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, geospatial, subplot, colorbar, colormap

> **This questions is vaguely answered elsewhere. Therefore, please answer it before down voting and marking it as duplicate. I have searched Stackoverflow and MATLAB forum**

I am trying to plot the spatial plot of India (see below), with multiple subplots.
Here I want to use one representative color bar as shown in the figure.

The color bar which I am getting is for the last subplots, and it's values does not corresponds with other subplots.

Below is, how I am trying to add the color bar and respective output

```
ax(1)=subplot(2,3,1)

worldmap('India');
shape=shaperead('India.shp',  'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(shape, 'FaceColor', 'w')
hold on
geoshow(lat,lon,data_fill, 'DisplayType', 'surface');
colormap('hsv');

.
.
.

ax(6)=subplot(2,3,6)

worldmap('India');
shape=shaperead('India.shp',  'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(shape, 'FaceColor', 'w')
hold on
geoshow(lat,lon,data_fill, 'DisplayType', 'surface');
colormap('hsv');


h=colorbar;

cmin = min(data_fill_of_all_sub_plot);
cmax = max(data_fill_of_all_sub_plot);

if mod(cmax,5)==0
    cmax=cmax+5;
else
    cmax=cmax+(5-mod(cmax,5));
end
caxis([cmin cmax])  % to fix the colormap scale

set(h, 'Position', [.95 .42 .01 .5])
```

Output

[image]

How to put a single color bar for all the subplots?

Comment: I don't understand: you want a single colorbar for all subplots and showing your code outputing exactly that. what is the question?

Comment: I am getting single colorbar for all subplots but the colorbar values do not correspond with other subplots. It is like I am putting colorbar for last subplot only. Here I have `caxis([cmin cmax])' used in ax(6)=subplot(2,3,3) only, I guess now, need to include it in ax(1), ax(2), ax(3), ax(4) and ax(5) as well. Am I right?

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying. Why dont you use caxis in the others also then?

Comment: yes, it works when I add caxis in others as well.

Comment: then, if it works, what is your question?

Comment: Earlier I was not including `caxis` under each subplot that was causing error. I got my solution now. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the mistake

```
caxis([cmin cmax])
```

is required to be included in every subplot section.

In present code it is only included after `ax(6)=subplot(2,3,6)`